# How to prove the modular multiplication property?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

In Number Theory, I have seen many a times the following property being used though I don't know what it's called formally (that makes it harder to Google):

```
(a * b) (mod n) = (a mod n) * (b mod n)
```

What is this called and how can it be formally proved?

Comment: It's the *definition* of multiplication modulo $n$, after it has been shown it does not depend on the choice of the representatives in each class.

Comment: This notation can be a little confusing if you're trying to do this on a computer.

Let `a=15`, `b=42`, and `n=12`.

`(a * b) % n = 6`

`(a % n) * (b % n) = 18`

However, `((a % n) * (b % n)) % n = 6`.

From what I read at https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/modular-multiplication, the "multiplication property of modular arithmetic" is

`(a * b) % n = ((a % n) * (b % n)) % n`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $a=xn+a'$ and $b=yn+b'$, where all are whole numbers, then $a'=a\text{ mod }n$ and $b'=b\text{ mod }n$.  It's then easy enough to multiply them:

$$ab=(xn+a')(yn+b')=(xyn+xb'+ya')n+a'b'$$

Take mod $n$ of both sides, and it should then be clear that

$$ab\equiv a'b'\pmod n$$

Comment: sorry for the very stupid question, how do you deduce the final equation from the previous one?

Comment: By definition, $mn+c\equiv c\pmod n$. Can you see what $m$ and $c$ are?

Comment: m and c be any integer? so how does this relate to what you wrote above?

Comment: ok so is the logic that xyn + xb' + ya' any integer hence it is m, then you get mn + a'b' = ab?

Comment: @mkheifetz yes.